# comparing each element in a string with another string at the same position

Tags: python, string, loops, python-3.x, compare

i want to compare a student's answer to the model answer. the student undertakes a test of multiple choice questions. there is a total of 5 questions and each question has 3 multiple choices.
the student chooses the following choices for all questions: "12231". e.g: for Q(1): student picks option "1",for Q(2): student picks option "2"...etc.
now, i need to calculate the student's total mark by comparing it with the Model answer: "12132". This student received a mark of 3/5.
*The student's answer will always be as the same length as the model one. e.g. the student wont skip any questions.*

i need to do the exact same thing, but with hundreds of students. can i do it using a code? i can only think of using a for loop and iterating the students answer, but i cannot think of a way to compare both together and calculate the student's mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you have a question that ends with "in another ___ at the same position", the answer is almost always `zip`.

If you `zip` together two strings, like the student's answers and the answer key, you get an iterable of pairs: the student's first answer and the answer key's first answer, then the two second answers, and so on.

So, if you want to count how many answers a student got right, you just loop over the `zip`, using a `for` statement or comprehension. For example:

```
score = sum(student==correct for student, correct in zip(student_answers, answer_key))
```

This uses a little extra trick: if you sum up a bunch of Boolean values, the True values count as 1, and the False values as 0. But otherwise, there's nothing more to than looping over `zip`.

And if you want to do this for each student's answers in a list of students, that's just another loop around this one. For example:

```
all_student_scores = []
for student_answers in all_student_answers:
    score = sum(student==correct for student, correct in zip(student_answers, answer_key)
    all_student_scores.append(score)
```

Or, if you want to be super-concise:

```
all_student_scores = [sum(student==correct for student, correct in zip(student_answers, answer_key)
                      for student_answers in all_student_answers]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [distance](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Distance/0.1) package - it provides a [hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) calculator:

```
import distance
distance.hamming("12231", "22131")
```

Now, if you have a list of student answers (str) and the model, you can do:

```
def score(student_answers,model):
    return len(model)-[distance.hamming(ans,model) for ans in student_answers]
```

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately we're not allowed to import anything.

Comment: @Moh'dH in this case, use abarnert's answer